# Error reported when saving dataframe with date as object into a parquet file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parquet, fastparquet

I'm trying to save a dataframe with `Date` as a column as parquet file. The `Date` series is in the type of `object`.

On one computer, there is no problems (`pandas` version is 1.4.2, `fastparquet` version is 0.7.2). However, when I tried it on another computer (with the same version of pandas and fastparquet), error was reported like this.

```
ValueError: Can't inter object conversion type:
0  2016-01-01
1  2016-02-01
2  2016-03-01
```

I did some research, it seems that the type of `Date` has to be converted from `object` to `datetime`. However, if so, why does it work on my previous computer. Are there any ways to fix this issue and keep `Date` as `dtype`? Thanks.

Comment: can you provide the code you use to save the data as parquet? It's possible that on one environment you have pyarrow installed and it preempts the use of fastparquet.

Comment: @0x26res thanks. sorry the code is quite long, have no way to provide. So pyarrow and fastparquet can affect each other. I'd better to install only one of them, right?

Comment: Or you can specify which engine you want to use when calling read_parquet with `engine="fastparquet"` or `engine="pyarrow"`